# UBI error: ubi_compare_lebs: unsupported on-flash UBI format

Tags: linux-kernel, spi, ubifs

I need to make a ubi based partition, while executing ubiattach below error is coming for (29MiB partition)

I could able to fomrat attach and mount a partition with 2MiB.. issue is happening with 29 MiB partition.

Could someone help on this

Kernel verion: 3.10.14

`[root@root:~]# ubiformat /dev/mtd6`
ubiformat: mtd6 (nor), size 30408704 bytes (29.0 MiB), 928 eraseblocks of 32768 bytes (32.0 KiB), min. I/O size 256 bytes

libscan: scanning eraseblock 927 -- 100 % complete

ubiformat: 928 eraseblocks have valid erase counter, mean value is 0

ubiformat: formatting eraseblock 927 -- 100 % complete

`[root@root:~]# ubiattach /dev/ubi_ctrl -m 6`

[ 2033.369743] UBI: attaching mtd6 to ubi0

[ 2033.373794] UBI assert failed in io_init at 673 (pid 116)

[ 2033.379396] CPU: 0 PID: 116 Comm: ubiattach Not tainted 3.10.14-svn3 #13

[ 2033.386388] Stack : 00000006 8003b6c0 00000000 805a0000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
          00000000 00000000 805a2e2a 0000003c 8198c1d8 81a0c800 00000000 00000000
          00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
          00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 8091fd00 8091fd74 804c8d10
          805321c7 8003cb24 774cd000 804c8d10 00000000 00000074 8198c1d8 8091fce8
          ...

[ 2033.423436] Call Trace:

[ 2033.425980] [<80020ca4>] show_stack+0x48/0x70

[ 2033.430501] [<80417f10>] dump_stack+0x20/0x2c

[ 2033.435040] [<8027b568>] ubi_attach_mtd_dev+0x3b8/0xc80

[ 2033.440464] [<8027c104>] ctrl_cdev_ioctl+0xe4/0x1d4

[ 2033.445538] [<800e7b5c>] vfs_ioctl+0x2c/0x4c

[ 2033.449961] 
[ 2033.696833] UBI error: ubi_compare_lebs: unsupported on-flash UBI format

[ 2033.704427] UBI error: ubi_attach_mtd_dev: failed to attach mtd6, error -22

ubiattach: error!: cannot attach mtd6
           error 22 (Invalid argument)

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Hi @Miuis, We were using an 32 MB SPI nor flash and i have not set the addressing mode to 4 byte mode. This change fixed our issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved by enabling 4 byte addressing mode as my SPI NOR size was 32 MB.